# How to force useEffect to wait until data is received in other components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I initialize user data in the gateway component and distribute the data to other components through redux stores. Therefore, if a user directly goes to the other components, then the web app breaks down.

I want to make sure other components to wait to execute the useEffect until the initialization has been done in the main component.

the 'props.places' are the one that is coming from the gateway component -> redux store. How can I force them to wait until they are initialized?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //convert incoming data to props
    console.log(props.places);
    let convert = [];
    for (const converted of props.places.results) {
      convert.push({
        lat: converted.coordinates.lat,
        lng: converted.coordinates.lng,
      });
    }

    setFacilities((facilities) => ({ ...facilities }, convert));
    console.log(facilities);
  }, [props.places]);
```

Comment: Are you looking for the component to wait to render until `props.places` has data? You can wrap the inside in an if-statement and have it conditionally render something based on whether the data is loaded or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add some data checks to your `useEffect` and render something else unless data is ready:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.places) {
            // do something
        }
    }, [props.places]);

    if (!props.places) return 'Waiting for places';

    return ... // normal rendering 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function YourFunctionalComponentName(props) {
    useEffect(()=>{
    },[props.places]);

    if (Object.keys(props.places).length>0){  // assuming props.places is an object
     return ..your jsx} 
    }
```